# Mathematica Manipulate & PopupMenu

Tags: dynamic, popup, controls, wolfram-mathematica

I'm new here and I've one question about the Manipulate function i Mathematica: I need to plot some data of a nested list where the first coordinate selects a category (of stocks, like banks, automobiles, pharmaceuticals, ...) and inside every category there are years and months coordinates, so it should be something like

```
In:= list[[cat]][[yr]][[mnth]]
Out= {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

which are sorted stock prices belonging to category `cat`.

Now I'd like to plot this with an dynamic index in `Manipulate` with a `PopupMenu` which allows to select the category i need to plot: I already have a vector `sect` which at position `cat` has the sector referring to `cat` in list (which is to say `sect[[i]]` is the category of `list[[i]]`), but results are poor.

I've tried to use `Manipulate[...,{index,sect}]` and it seems to be the right way since there actually is a popup menu in the output, but it still gives error about syntax in the control cycle I need to plot only the right sector, something like

`If[ sect[[j]] == index, Plot[ list[[j]] ] ]`.

So I'm stuck here, thanks to anyone will help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced your data structure is optimal, but here's a sample set of data:

```
data2 = {
{"stock",
{
 Range[6], Range[6, 12],
 Range[12, 18]
 },
{
 Range[18, 24], Range[24, 30],
 Range[30, 36]
 }
},
{"bank",
Table[Range[i, i + 5], {i, 1, 18, 6}],
Table[Range[i, i + 5], {i, 18, 30, 6}]
}
};
```

and the Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[data2[[cat, year, month]]],
{{cat, 1, "Category"}, {1 -> "stock", 2 -> "bank"}, 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{year, 2, "Year"}, {2 -> "2010", 3 -> "2011"}, 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{month, 1, "Month"}, {1 -> "Jan", 2 -> "Feb", 3 -> "Mar"}, 
ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```